# PRISM WPF - Navigation creates new view every time

Tags: wpf, navigation, unity-container, prism

I'm using PRISM 4 Navigation API with Unity in WPF. I have a tree-view that initiates a *RequestNavigate* passing in the selected tree node's ID (*GUID*).

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.DetailRegion,
    ViewNames.SiteView + "?ID=" + site.ID);
```

In my module, I have registered the view/view-model like so:

```
_container.RegisterType<SiteDetailsViewModel>();
_container.RegisterType<object, SiteDetailsView>(ViewNames.SiteView);
```

When I select different nodes from the tree view, the *DetailsRegion* displays the *SiteDetailsView* as expected, but when I like to navigate back to the same node, a new view/view-model is created.

I tried to break at `IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)` but this method appears to never be called.

Where have i gone wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was in such a place that I never expected... Debugging the Navigation API lead me to the `RegionNavigationContentLoader`

```
public object LoadContent(IRegion region, NavigationContext navigationContext)
```

When i stepped further down the code, I noticed a call to:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<object> GetCandidatesFromRegion(
    IRegion region,
    string candidateNavigationContract)
```

I noticed that the naming here is key to matching the view to the view-model.

In my example, the name for each part was:

```
public class SiteDetailsViewModel { ... } // ViewModel

public class SiteDetailsView { ... } // View

ViewNames.SiteView = "SiteView" // ViewName constant
```

When I inadvertently made the following change:

```
ViewName.SiteView = "SiteDetailsView"
```

Everthing worked.

**Conclusion**

> The name of the ViewModel must start
>   with the same name you used to
>   identify your view.

I tested this out by changing my view to:

```
public class MyView { ... }
```

and still using the same view name to register with the container and navigation:

```
_container.RegisterType<object, MyView>(ViewNames.SiteView);

...

_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.DetailRegion,
    ViewNames.SiteView + "?ID=" + site.ID);
```

This seems to work also. So it seems the name of the View-Model is intrinsically linked to the view name used to navigate to that view.

**NOTE**

This is only when you're using IoC and Unity with the PRISM 4 Navigation API. This doesn't seem to happen when using MEF.

**Further Investigation**

I am also aware that some [guides](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kashiffl/archive/2011/03/10/prism-4-region-navigation-with-silverlight-frame-navigation-and-unity.aspx) have told us to use the `typeof(MyView).FullName` when registering the view with the Container...

```
_container.RegisterType<object, MyView>(typeof(MyView).FullName);
```

I personally think this is a mistake. By using the view's full name, you are creating a depending between the view and any one who wishes to navigate to that view...

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.DetailRegion,
    typeof(MyView).FullName + "?ID=" + site.ID);
```

Comment: yeah, weird behavior, i found this info in comments to this issue http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/7468?PendingVoteId=7468

Answer (score 0):

The registration of the View and the ViewModel is the problem. To have only one view you have to use a different lifetime manager. Without specifying a lifetime manager the `TransientLifetimeManager` is used which always returns a new instance on resolve. To have only one single instance you have to use the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` or the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`:

```
_container.RegisterType<SiteDetailsViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterType<object, SiteDetailsView>(ViewNames.SiteView, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```